# How to convert string to int in this specific situation?

Tags: java, exception, integer, int

The following piece of code:

```
if (e.getSource() == btnRe) {
  lblCounter.setText(count - count);
}
```

Throws the exception:

```
Exception: Incompatible tpyes: int cannot be converted to String "count - count"
```

I don't know how to change count into an integer that the method setText can read.

Comment: Use `String.valueOf()`

Comment: Use `String#valueOf(count - count)`. But, on the other hand, `count - count` isn't `0`? Or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Objective is to go from page to page and there's a counter in the middle and instead of going back all the way to 0 i wanted to make a button that you simply press and takes you automatically back to 0.

Comment: What do you want the text to be? `"0"`?

Comment: 1 so I would take the users current page, ex: "2234". There are arrows to go higher or lower in number but to make it easier there's a reset button that takes you back to zero, or one i haven't thought about that yet.

Answer (score 2):

`count - count` is `0`. You could use

```
lblCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count - count));
```

or just

```
lblCounter.setText("0");
```

Comment: Yeah count - count = 0 i was gonna add ++ to it.

Comment: @Hooga And that would be `"1"`.

Comment: This makes sense to set it to 0, but the overall project so that there's a counter, you press up and it goes up by one. After a point you get to a high number and you're done doing what you were gonna do. At this point youre at like page 600 and you wanna go back to 0 fast, so you press the reset button.    lblCounter.setText("0"); just sets the text to zero but if you press up it goes to 601 i want to start back at 1. You get me?

Comment: @Hooga So `String.valueOf(count % 600)`?

Comment: value of int count is always changing so no. I have to subtract it by itself.

Comment: @Hooga No, you really don't. The modulus operand will do what you want (e.g. 601 % 600 is 1 and 1 % 600 is 1).

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate `""` to the equation, java will know you're passing a string.
If count is a `String`, this should do the trick.

```
    if (e.getSource() == btnRe) {

        lblCounter.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(count) - Integer.parseInt(count)));
    }
```

Or, if it is an `int`, then use this.

```
    if (e.getSource() == btnRe) {

        lblCounter.setText("" + (count -count));
    }
```